# Is there a way to have Azure Data Factories use Windows Integrated Authentication for an On-Prem File System Linked Service?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-data-factory

I'm trying create an Azure Data Factory to copy files from a local, on-prem file system to Blob Storage. However, when creating the Linked Service the only apparent options are to specify a username directly in the ADF or via KeyVault. I want to use the current Windows Login to perform the file copy and not have to manage credentials. I'm fine with running the service as a specific user, but that doesn't solve the ADF wanting a username / password.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are trying to copy from in-premise db the cloud . The integration which you are talking about can be achieved by using [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#generate-managed-identity) .but if I am understanding right you must be using an IR which you are running locally , when you update your credential in future , you will have to update that on the IR also .Going the AKV  rourte should not be very difficult .